# PowerShell one-liner to find inactive computers in AD

Tags: powershell

I require a AD powershell one liner that will return all active computers (lastlogonate > 30 days).

```
$inactive = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
 
Get-ADComputer -filter {lastlogondate -gt $inactive }
```

I can do the above but I ideally need a one liner to include in a framework that executes a list of queries. I thought the below would work:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter {lastlogondate -gt $(Get-Date).AddDays(-30) }
```

But I get an error "...value of argument "path" is not valid"

Answer (score 1):

Replace the curly braces with quotes...

```
Get-ADComputer -filter "lastlogondate -gt '$((Get-Date).AddDays(-30))'"
```

Comment: sorry, marked as answered too early. the query parses but returns no results. the query took a long time to return the result as our estate is large so i thought it was working

Comment: works in my env for sure... and show results, did you changed anything?